# BackboneJS: Avoid calling _.bind()

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, scope

I am using the BackboneJS framework and run into a situation whereby I have to constantly wrap my functions into `_.bind()` to keep `this` in the right scope.

An example would be a simple AJAX call. JQuery by default changes `this` to the AJAX Request object, but I want to keep my view as `this`:

```
var AwesomeView = BackboneView.extend({

   firstFunction : function() {
      $.getJSON(
         "/test",
          {},
           _.bind(function(aData) {
               this.secondFunction(aData);
           }, this)
      )
   } ,

   secondFunction : function(aData) {
      console.log(aData)
   }

});
```

I have plenty of examples throughout my codebase of this occuring and it works, but seems kind of hacked.

So my question is, is there a more elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are both ways to avoid using `_.bind` as well as other ways to use it that are more elegant.

I like using `_.bind` and `_.bindAll` in my code. But I find this implementation to be a bit more elegant.

```
var AwesomeView = BackboneView.extend({
  initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'func1', 'func2');
    BackboneView.prototype.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
  },
  ...
});
```

Here you bind the views functions `func1` and `func2` to the context of your view. And you can simply call them from any context "normally," using your example:

```
func1 : function() {
  $.getJSON("/test",{}, this.func2);
},
...
```

Note that `Function.prototype.bind` is available in ECMA script 5.1.

You could also use `call` but it will look similar to your code now.

```
   firstFunction : function() {
      var _this = this;
      $.getJSON(
         "/test",
          {},
           function(aData) {
             _this.secondFunction.call(_this, aData);
           });
      )
   }
```

Comment: I believe this is the best practice, not just per Backbone's docs but when binding methods in general.